# Append tag to end of URL on form select

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have this:

```
<select onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_top')">
```

How do I change so that instead it appends the 'value' to the end of the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean change the current page's URL by appending the value? Is the value (the options in the select) guaranteed to be valid paths that can be appended? If so...

```
<select onchange="location.href+=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
```

Comment: i was about to suggest something similar, but maybe you need to put an `&` or perhaps `&amp;` before the 'value'

Comment: The way question is written, it seems like that the values are paths but yes, that is an assumption. I would update as the OP posts more details.